# Is there a simplified solution to find minimum distance between two approaching cars?

Tags: calculus, vectors, physics, kinematics

The problem is as follows:

> Two buggies one orange and the other blue are passing through an
>   intersection with constants speeds of $v_{orange}=6\,\frac{m}{s}$ and
>   $v_{blue}=6\sqrt{3}\,\frac{m}{s}$ respectively. Find the minimum
>   approach in meters between the orange and blue buggies.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&10\,m\\
2.&12\,m\\
3.&24\,m\\
4.&36\,m\\
\end{array}$

What I attempted to do is to establish the equations in the intersection as follows:

For x:

$-40\cos23^{\circ}+6t$

For y:

$-40\sin23^{\circ}+6\sqrt{3}t$

Therefore the distance for those would be the norm.

$\left\langle -40\cos23^{\circ}+6t, -40\sin23^{\circ}+6\sqrt{3}t \right\rangle$

$\left\|\left\langle -40\cos23^{\circ}+6t, -40\sin23^{\circ}+6\sqrt{3}t \right\rangle\right\|=d$

$d^2=\left(-40\cos23^{\circ}+6t\right)^2+ (-40\sin23^{\circ}+6\sqrt{3}t)^2$

Taking the derivative and equating to zero would give me the minimum time isn't it?

$\left(\left(-40\cos23^{\circ}+6t\right)^2+ (-40\sin23^{\circ}+6\sqrt{3}t)^2\right)'=$

$(d^2)'=12\left(-40\cos23^{\circ}+6t\right)+12\sqrt{3}\left(-40\sin23^{\circ}+6\sqrt{3}t\right)=0$

Simplifying:

$-40\cos23^{\circ}+6t+\sqrt{3}\left(-40\sin23^{\circ}+6\sqrt{3}t\right)=0$

$-40\cos23^{\circ}-40\sqrt{3}\sin23^{\circ}=-18t-6t$

$-40\cos23^{\circ}-40\sqrt{3}\sin23^{\circ}=-24t$

Further simplification and multiplication by $(-1)$:

$5\cos23^{\circ}+5\sqrt{3}\sin23^{\circ}=3t$

$t=\frac{5\left(\cos23^{\circ}+\sqrt{3}\sin23^{\circ}\right)}{3}$

Then condensing the trigonometric expressions by:

$t=\frac{5\times 2\left(\frac{1}{2}\cos23^{\circ}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin23^{\circ}\right)}{3}$

$t=\frac{5\times 2\left(\sin 30^{\circ}\cos23^{\circ}+\cos 30^{\circ}\sin23^{\circ}\right)}{3}$

$t=\frac{5\times 2 \sin 53^{\circ}}{3}$

Assuming that $\sin 53^{\circ}= \frac{4}{5}$

$t=\frac{5\times 2 \times \frac{4}{5}}{3}=\frac{8}{3}$

Then this would be the minimum time for both buggies to be closer.

Therefore the minimum distance between them would be the square root of evaluating that time in the function stated in the beginning:

$d^2=\left(-40\cos23^{\circ}+6t\right)^2+ (-40\sin23^{\circ}+6\sqrt{3}t)^2$

But here's where it is coming ugly:

$d^2= 40^2\cos^2 23^{\circ}-480\cos23^{\circ}t+36t^2$

$d^2=40^2\cos^{2}23^{\circ}-480\cos23^{\circ}t+36t^2+40^2\sin^{2}23^{\circ}-480\sqrt{3}\sin23^{\circ}t+108t^2$

$d^2=40^2\sin^{2}23^{\circ}+40^2\cos^{2}23^{\circ}-480t\left(\cos23^{\circ}+\sqrt{3}\sin23^{\circ} \right )+144t^2$

$d^2=40^2\left(\sin^{2}23^{\circ}+\cos^{2}23^{\circ}\right )-480\times 2t \left(\frac{1}{2}\cos23^{\circ}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin23^{\circ} \right )+144t^2$

$d^2=40^2\left(1\right )-480\times 2t \left(\sin30^{\circ}\cos23^{\circ}+\cos30^{\circ}\sin23^{\circ} \right )+144t^2$

$d^2=1600-480\times 2t \left(\sin53^{\circ} \right )+144t^2$

Again assuming $\sin 53^{\circ}= \frac{4}{5}$:

$d^2=1600-960t\left(\frac{4}{5} \right)+144t^2$

$d^2=1600-768 t+144t^2$

Then all will left to do is taking the square root to that expression evaluating with $t=\frac{8}{3}$

$d=\sqrt{1600-768 \left(\frac{8}{3}\right)+144\left(\frac{8}{3}\right)^2}$

$d=\sqrt{1600-768 \left(\frac{8}{3}\right)+144\left(\frac{64}{9}\right)}$

$d=24$

Therefore the minimum distance would be $24\,m$

I believe this would be the answer but as it can be seen, this procedure was very exhausting in terms of calculation and keeping up with the right numbers. Does it exist a way to **simplify** it or to ease it?. Can somebody help me here?.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the origin in the orange one the problem reduces to find the minum distance form the origin of the parametric line

$$(x(t),y(t))=(40\cos 23°,-40 \sin 23°)+t(-6, 6\sqrt 3)$$

which is attained when $(x(t),y(t))$ is perpendicular to $(-6, 6\sqrt 3)$ that is

$$[(40\cos 23°,-40 \sin 23°)+t(-6, 6\sqrt 3)]\cdot (-6, 6\sqrt 3)=0$$

$$(40\cos 23°-6t)(-6)+(-40 \sin 23°+6t\sqrt 3)6\sqrt 3=0$$

$$-240\cos 23°+36t-240\sqrt 3 \sin 23°+108 t=0$$

$$t=\frac{5 \cos 23°+5 \sqrt 3 \sin 23°}{3} \approx \frac 83$$

Comment: As the OP of this question I must say that the question requested the minimum distance not the minimum time. Actually i dont feel comfortable working with parametric lines. Yet i find it interesting. Im still stuck on **how** you obtained those equations. But more importantly **how** you can get the distance from the time found?.

Comment: Can you answer my comment please?. Why the dot product is zero?. Could it be that is this due a vector identity which I haven't noticed?. Does in general terms would simplify the things assuming the origin in one of the vehicles in this kind of problems?

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to solve the problem in the relative frame of reference. Let the orange car be at the origin and the blue car initially at $(40,0)$. The relative velocity of the blue car is

$$(6\sqrt3\cos67+6\cos23,\>6\sqrt3\sin67-6\cos23)=12(\sin53,\>\cos53)$$

and the equation of its path is

$$y = \frac{\cos53}{\sin53}(x-40)=\frac34(x-40),\>\>\>\text{or} \>\>\>3x-4y-120=0$$

Then, their minimum approach is just the distance from the origin to the line, given by the distance formula,

$$d=\frac{|3(0)-4(0)-120|}{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}}=24$$

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind your answer? Because i dont know how you got those equations. Where does $(6 \sqrt 3 \cos^\circ 67+ 6\cos^\circ 23$ and $(6 \sqrt 3 \cos^\circ 67+ 6\cos^\circ 23$ comes from and **why**? **how** and **why** the equation of its path is $y=\frac{\cos 53}{\sin 53} (x-40)$? Can you put the **justification** for these expressoions because im stuck with these steps.